# How can i change this query to Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT to_date(
           (
             SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(from_tz(cast(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tehran', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) GROUP_DATE
             FROM REPORT_EVENTS
           ), 'yyyy-mm-dd') - (ROWNUM * 7) group_date
FROM (SELECT 1 counter
      FROM dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52
)
```

Comment: That's going to be tough because you're using a lot of mysql functions. You might be better off just using `DB::statement`.

Comment: This is too broad to answer.  Stack Overflow doesn't generally allow "convert this code for me" questions.

Comment: Why would you want to, I hate query builders...

Comment: Sometimes it's better to write more complex queries like the one you have using DB::statement()

Comment: I need the eleqouent style to have laravel object collection in order to add Some Scopes (condition) to the object and then pass it through the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectRaw()` and `DB::raw()` to handle complex SQL statements

```
YourModel::selectRaw("to_date(("
            . "SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(from_tz(cast(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Tehran', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) GROUP_DATE "
            . "FROM REPORT_EVENTS), 'yyyy-mm-dd') - (ROWNUM * 7) group_date")
    ->from(DB::raw("SELECT 1 counter FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52"));
```